# how to calculate the processing time?

Tags: time, processor

Processing times for 5 processes were given. how will I find out the minimum average waiting time the processes have to wait in order to get executed if TWO PROCESSORS are given.

Comment: What do you need? Pseudo-code or a general explaination? What do you have so far? Do the processes have to be executed in-order, or is the goal to find the most efficient way of executing them? Do two processes always have to start at the same time (is that why there is a waiting time?)

Comment: HI Leigh!!the goal is fine the efficient way of executing them..no the processes need not start at the same time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On any given processor, the total waiting time for an ordered set of processes taking time P<sub>1</sub>..P<sub>N</sub> to complete is the total of individual elapsed times multiplied by the number of waiting processes remaining:

(N - 1)P<sub>1</sub> + (N - 2)P<sub>2</sub> + ... + P<sub>N-1</sub>.

This reveals that waiting time is hit by a multiple of the cost of earlier processes, with the consequence that we need to get shorter-running jobs over with as early as possible and minimise queue length.  Say we sort the process durations and call them A, B, C, D, and E (the longest-running job).  If we contrast the following prioritorisation:

```
Processor 1: A, B, C, D
Processor 2: E
Total waiting time: 3A + 2B + C
```

...with...

```
Processor 1: A, B, D
Processor 2: C, E
Total waiting time: 2A + B + C
```

We can clearly see the second configuration saves (A + B) total waiting time, and the benefit of distributing the jobs in a 3:2 split.  Equally, the 2A + B + C formula can only be worse if we swapped D or E for any of A, B or C, as we know A <= B <= C <= D <= E.

There are only two alternative 3:2 permutations given D and E don't partake in the waiting time calculation (they will be denoted with X hereafter).

```
Processor 1: A, C, X
Processor 2: B, X
Total waiting time: 2A + C + B  [no change]

Processor 1: A, X
Processor 2: B, C, X
Total waiting time: A + 2B + C  [maybe worse as B>=A]
```

Thus, the optimal and equally satisfactory orderings are: ABX/CX and ACX/BX.

Answer (score 0):

Perform shortest job first scheduling.
 Then find the average waiting time.